# numpy elementwise multiply vector and matrix that have the same number of rows

Tags: machine-learning, python, numpy

I have a matrix and a vector that both have n rows. I would like to have the kth row of the matrix be elementwise multiplied by the kth element in my vector, without a for loop! I have already tried np.multiply, and it doesn't work.

Is this possible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to DataScience SE!  This question is more about Numpy and Python, so it would be better to look on StackOverflow for an answer. It would also be helpful if you post example data so people can test it and give you a tested answer.

Comment: Kindly provide an example of input matrices and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

numpy.multiply can do it. It has matrix multiply semantics so you need to transpose the matrix. 
Is below what you were looking for?

```
In [19]: >>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))

In [20]: >>> x2 = np.arange(3.0)

In [21]: np.multiply(x1.T, x2.T).T
Out[21]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [12., 14., 16.]])
```

Comment: You could also use `x1 * x2[:,None]`.